# Active Admin index with scope results in NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, custom-scope

Working with Rails 4.2.6, I have this user model with a custom scope. Here is my models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active_customers, -> { patient.where.not(customer_id: nil) }
```

I am trying to display an index of all the active_customers using Active Admin, here is my admin/customer.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, as: "Customer" do
  menu priority: 8, label: proc{ I18n.t "admin.financial_report" }, parent: 'dev'
  actions :index

controller do
  def scoped_collection
    User.active_customers
  end
end
```

An it works locally and in staging but it crashes in production server.

I already have an index for all the patients that works perfectly in every enviroment. Here is the admin/patient.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, as: "Patient" do
 menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t "admin.users" }
 permit_params [:nickname, :name, :surname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :therapist_id, :created_by_admin, :randword, :phone, :active]
 actions :all, except: [:destroy]

 controller do
   def scoped_collection
     User.patient
   end
```

Logs in production doesn't display any trace of the SQL query because it seems to break before:

```
Started GET "admin/customers"
Processing by Admin::CustomersController#index
Completed 500 Internal Server Error
```

After checking the result for rake routes I can see that there is no route for "admin/customers" but it doesn't breaks locally neither staging server.
Any clue about why is it happening?

In my routes.rb I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

In staging we have:

```
User.patient.count => 397
Benchmark.realtime { User.patient } => 0.0014501959958579391
User.active_customers.count => 99
Benchmark.realtime { User.active_customers } => 0.0016011869884096086
```

And in production:

```
User.patient.count => 27853
Benchmark.realtime { User.patient } => 0.007111124003131408
User.active_customers.count => 496
Benchmark.realtime { User.active_customers } => 0.0040691940012038685
```

So, although the difference of numbers between enviroments I don't think that the reason for the memory error in production is the number of users.

Also tried to use the scope that works in patient.rb in the customer.rb and it crashed:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    User.patient
  end
```

After that I tried changing as:"Customer" to as:"User" and crashed again:

```
  ActiveAdmin.register User, as: "User" do
```

If the scope that works in patient.rb doesn't work in customer.rb it makes me discard the idea that the problem is caused just because a lack of memory.
Pretty sure that the problem is related to the way I use the scope in the active admin or my syntax in customer.rb but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with this piece of code? I think it has nothing to do with your scopes, it could be anything. Don't you think you need a server having more memory?

Comment: Just edited the question adding some info and assumptions. Using a scope that works in a different Active Admin index results in the same error so I understand that the problem is directly related to a lack of memory. Of course adding more memory will always help.

Answer (score 1):

I would first check the SQL statements in your Rails log for anything unexpected.  It's not obvious to me what is wrong, but personally I would do the scoping at the ActiveRecord model level instead of ActiveAdmin, eg:

```
class ActiveCustomer < User
  default_scope { where.not(customer_id: nil) }
end

ActiveAdmin.register ActiveCustomer do
  ...
end
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I already edited my question because it was not clear that the scope is declared in the model file. Also added the output for the logs before crashing. It doesn't get to the SQL, it seems to break trying to GET "admin/customers" so I tested the scope using the rails console that's way I added the results for count and benchmark.

Comment: Hmm... I'm suggesting subclassing the model and then registering the subclassed model without an alias so you shouldn't need the scoped collection in the controller...

Comment: Thanks Piers C for your advice and excuse me for all these days without any answer. It has been kind of "lot of work in the office" days. I tried your proposal and for sure this will be in my set of tools in the future but the server keeps returning the memory error. I will continue studying the issue to avoid to keep stuck in this point of the development I decided to try a different approach adding a custom view done from scratch with its own controller and without any use of the Active Admin. It feels like reinventing the wheel but it was the fastest solution.